# Primefaces issue with Datatable summary row

Tags: primefaces

I am using JSF 2.1.26 with primefaces 4.0. I am facing some strange issue while trying to show the summary row in the datatable.

So , basically what I am doing is saving a notesList (think of it as list of string) into the database. The save operation is successful and I can clearly see all the data in the DB.
But when I pull the same data from the DB and try to publish two columns from the record as summary row ,it comes out as blank for some of the rows.
For Eg.. If I save 5 rows using noteList then I see the summary row for only 2 or 3 records and rest appear blank even though  they are present in DB.

Here is the interesting part...

If I try to save the records one at a time using a for loop,  instead of using  LIST, I no longer face the issue. 
**The contents in the DB are exactly the same in both the cases.**

```
for (ABC abc : XYZ)) {
                NotesDto notesDto = new NotesDto();
                //notesDtoList.add(notesDto);   occurs
                notesService.saveNote(notesDto);  //This works fine
            }
            //notesService.saveNotes(notesDtoList);  ---- This takes the whole list at a time
```

Below is the sample.xhtml file

```
<p:dataTable var="noteanddisp" value="#{notesBean.notesList}"
                            id="notesTable" editable="false" styleClass="smallGrid"
                            sortBy="insertedOn" sortOrder="descending"
                            widgetVar="notesTable">
                            <p:summaryRow>
                                <p:column colspan="6" styleClass="summaryRowClass">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{noteanddisp.statusText}"
                                        styleClass="NoteTextColumn"/>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{noteanddisp.noteText}"
                                        styleClass="NoteTextColumn"/>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:summaryRow>
```

Here, statustest and notestext are two columns in the record and one of them will be having value at a given time.

When I tried to inspect the code on chrome, I found that for the rows where summary row is coming up as blank, 'tr class=summaryrow' tag is missing in the generated html code**
I am confused as in why the tag is missing even though it has the value.

I tried debugging the code in eclipse as well and the pull operation is fetching all the records normally. Only during the **show** part something is going wrong.

Any help ?[image: Missing summary Row]

As you can see in the image source.png, 'tr class=ui-datatable-summary-row' tag is missing for some of the records.

[image: Source.png]

Comment: Step 1: Try 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 6.0, 6,1, 6.2

Comment: If your issue gets solved when you save your items 1 by 1, and the rest is the same, it isn't likely to be related to primefaces, but to a bug in your notes service/dao... And the content in the database can't be the same if the issue is present only when you saved it in one way.